# Publish Visio 2010 Document to Web with Multiple Hyperlinks per Object

Tags: microsoft-visio-2010

We have a process flow document that requires multiple hyperlinks per object. It appears that the only the [VML web format](http://blog.bvisual.net/2013/06/18/comparison-of-visio-save-as-web-outputs/) supports this.

Since we upgraded to Visio 2010, the Save As... HTML format dialog box is missing the publish button. We [need this button to](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-visio/publish-button-missing-in-visio-2010/26cb3c39-c980-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5) choose the VML format. However, [some sites claim](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/32ced63c-6b4f-4031-a860-9c103b481a9a/can-visio-2010-save-as-web-page-without-forcing-end-users-to-use-silverlight?forum=visiogeneral) that you can set the output to VML if you put the filename in quotes, though this does not work for us.

How can we get Visio 2010 to save to web in VML format so that we can have multiple hyperlinks per object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to [a bug in 2010 Standard Edition](http://tutorial.programming4.us/windows_7/microsoft-visio-2010---creating-web-pages-from-visio-drawings-(part-3)---fine-tuning-web-pages-and-battling-bugs---customizing-web-page-output--.aspx), there is a work around that will get you the Publish dialog:

1. Select the File tab, and choose "Save As"
2. Choose the folder where you want to save the file
3. Add the file name and extension (.html) with quotes around it, such as "MyDrawing.html"
4. **Leave the File type as 'drawing'.**
5. Press Save

At this point the Publish dialog should appear and allow you to select the desired options.

Also - since the Publish options are stored in the registry, you will only need to use this work around when you need to make a change to the settings.

After you do this, you will need to add the below line to the output file to fix a bug in the newer versions of IE where the page appears blank:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7, IE=8">
```

[Source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7161469f-e358-4bfe-899e-ad73ca522dab/publish-button-missing-in-visio-2010?forum=visiogeneral)